# ViewController observing an object property not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I'm starting to learn objective-c and my first app would be simple. I created a class to handle a timer. It has a property currentTime, a startAndPause method and a stopTimer method.

I'm initialising my Timer in the viewDidLoad method of my ViewController as :

```
 _minu = [[KUUMinuteur alloc] initWithDuration:@70];
```

Then, I want my ViewController to observe my _minu.currentTime property changes. So I did this :

```
[_minu addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentTime" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

And in my viewController, I wrote this method but it never triggers :

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Changing !!");
}
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. :(

(My App is a single View app.)

EDIT : forgot to translate tempsPublic to currentTime

Comment: try to call this line just after the addObserver: `_minu.currentTime = nil;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are never changing the `currentTime` property of `KUUMinuteur`.

I wonder if you are trying to directly update `_currentTime` ivar that backs your `currentTime` property. When changing the value of a property you do not want to use the ivar (other than the `init`, `dealloc`, and custom setter methods, if any):

```
_currentTime = ...;  // wrong
```

You want to use the setter, e.g.

```
self.currentTime = ...; // right
```

or

```
[self setCurrentTime:...]; // right
```

Make sure you use the setter or else the key-value notification will not take place.

See the [Use Accessor Methods to Set Property Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW5) section of the *Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide.* Or see the [Automatic Change Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/keyvalueobserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW1) section of the *Key-Value Observing Programming Guide.*

Comment: I have a method "decrementInt" on my KUUMinuteur that changes the tempsPublic property. This method also logs the tempsPublic property as it's changing. And It is.

Comment: Waow !! It works, thanks a lot !!

I thought that _tempPublic and self.tempsPublic was doing the same and  thinking that the former was a shortcut !!

Answer (score 0):

```
[_minu addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentTime" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

It should be `currentTime` instead of `tempsPublic`.

Comment: Thanks, my app is in french and I forgot to translate tempsPublic in cuurentTime for the Stackoverflow public. Sorry.